# Wordpress redirect to search like result

Tags: wordpress

I'm asking this question on behalf of my wife that has her own WordPress blog.

Recently urls like this: http://catinha.dk/au started redirecting to http://catinha.dk/2005/05/22/au-pair/ and http://catinha.dk/dansk redirects to http://catinha.dk/2005/10/08/danskundervisning/.

It appears that the direct is for "a url with a matching word in the title" or something like that since http://catinha.dk/foo will just give a 404.

I'm pretty sure this is a pretty trivial configuration that she somehow got wrong but we cannot figure how what has changed.

Udpdate:
We would like to avoid the redirect because it prevents another blog (http://catinha.dk/dansk) from working probably. http://catinha.dk/dansk is the root another WordPress installation.

She has been playing around with a FPT client so it is not unthinkable that there has been a change in .htaccess

Here is .htaccess for catinha.dk:

```
# BEGIN FAlbum
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^fotos/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?$ /wp-content/plugins/falbum/wp/album.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# END FAlbum
# -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^dansk.+$ /dansk/foo.php [L]
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This is the .htaccess file for catinha.dk/dansk:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dansk/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dansk/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless somebody was tooling around with the .htaccess file(s), it sounds to me like the permalinks were set to "post name" and then somehow got set to "day and name." That's the first thing I'd check. From your dashboard, go into "Settings > Permanlinks" and see which option is checked. If "day and name" is checked, check "post name" instead. Try that and report back!

Comment: Thanks, but we would like to prevent the redirect. Just updated the question.

Comment: The permalink option was set to "day and name".

Comment: Ah, you posted when I posted... did you try setting it to "post-name" ?

Comment: Tried "post-name" but same result :(

Comment: Weird. Post the .htaccess file perhaps? Maybe she did inadvertently change something through a GUI somehow.

Comment: Just added both .htaccess files to the question

Comment: Wordpress is trying to find the best match, not sure why it is sticking the date in, but it is definitely a problem with your permalinks. The proper page is http://catinha.dk/au-pair/ and will not redirect, but just "au" causes it to search for the best match based on your permalink settings. I would go there and make an arbitrary change, save it, then change back and save again to recreate the permalinks.